# Excel - Calculate Percent Variance Two Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I calculate a percent variance of multiple numbers on two different columns in excel and output 1 number? For example column a is 20 percent greater then column b average.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Are you struggling with the mathematical concept or how to translate it into Excel formulas? Please edit your question, add some sample data and enter the desired result. Explain the logic that leads to the result.

Comment: It was the translation. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula in cell D2 is

```
=(AVERAGE(A:A)/AVERAGE(B:B))-1
```

[image]